# Base internationalization hides/shows my views by language settings

Tags: xcode, ios6, internationalization

I use 'Base internationalization' in XCode to localize my storyboard.

After setting the languages: German, English, checking 'use base internationalization' in Xcode I have a very strange and annoying behaviour: when I add a view to a storyboard element, and run it in simulator, I can see the added view only when my simulator language is english, but I can see a totally empty white ui, when I set it to German.

Anybody seen something similar?

Answer (score 1):

Finally I have solved it.

This feature of XCode is pretty buggy, it takes time to get used to its annoying behaviour.

After creating a project, before you check base internationalization, you should open all storyboards once at least. You should also open localization string file(s). After you have to clean your project.

And after these steps you can set base internationalization.

And finally it works.

True story.